# Excel charts not showing correct time on x axis

Tags: excel

I have below 2 columns.

```
Transaction_Date    DLP_X
9/28/2016   5:45:57 AM
9/27/2016   4:58:33 AM
9/24/2016   6:01:47 AM
9/23/2016   5:35:52 AM
9/22/2016   5:25:09 AM
9/21/2016   5:25:20 AM
9/20/2016   6:34:12 AM
9/17/2016   6:01:23 AM
9/16/2016   5:08:15 AM
9/15/2016   4:58:30 AM
9/14/2016   4:58:21 AM
9/13/2016   4:58:05 AM
```

I am trying to make a 2-D line chart from above data. The date should go on X axis and corresponding time on Y axis, however excel showing only 12 AM on Y axis. I tried to change the chart type to X-Y scatter but it did not help. I am using Excel 2007.

[image]

Comment: When you have your data selected, is the `AM` part of it? I put your info. in and it worked for me, but note that the times aren't `5:45:57 AM`, but `05:45:57`.

Comment: There was formatting issue. Thanks anyways.